# TFS Release Artifacts - How to Link Version Control Artifacts?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, release-management

I am trying to setup some powershell scripts to be available on my TFS Release Agent.

From what I have learned thus far the way to do this is to link an artifact up and reference the artifact link in a PowerShell Task in TFS RM.

What I have trouble with is that TFS RM Artifacts will only allow me to download the entire Team Project in Version control while I only want powershell scripts in a specific subfolder downloaded to the agent.

I get an error message that says:

Field (Source Repository) Artifacts should have valid values

[image]

So, how do I link a SUBfolder of TFS as a downloadable artifact????

I there a custom task I can use to accomplish this instead?

I have yet to find one in the MarketPLace that downloads raw files in TFS Version Control binding and workspace free to execute on the Release agent server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Publish an artifact as part of your build process. You can easily control the exact folders/files that are published.

Comment: That won't work.  I don't want the solution to build every time I update a build script.

Comment: Then create a separate build and link it as a secondary artifact.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is that you can get the file(s) by using [Get a file REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/items#get-a-file).

1. Click Run On agent
2. Check Allow scripts to access OAuth token option (make sure the build service account has the permission to download the file)
3. Add PowerShell task to release definition (Type: Inline Script)

Arguments:

```
-url '$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)/_apis/tfvc/items?path=$/Scrum2015/ClassLibraryA/hello.ps1&api-version=1.0' -token "$(System.AccessToken)"  -filePath "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\hello.ps1"
```

Scripts:

```
Param([string]$url,
  [string]$token,
  [string]$filePath
)
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$token)))
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -OutFile $filePath
```

If want to download many files in a folder, you can [custom build task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task) to call PowerShell to create workspace and get files by using [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/).